# Manipulating Pandas Columns into different labels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-manipulation

lets say i have a dataframe like below

```
Destination ZIP Express Zone    Ground Zone
0   96700             12               9
1   96701             10               9
2   96702             12               9
2   96703             12               9
2   96704             12               9
```

i want to change it to this

```
Destination ZIP         Zone      Label
    0   96700             12      Express Zone         
    1   96700             9       Ground Zone
    2   96701             10      Express Zone
    2   96701             9       Ground Zone
    2   96702             12      Express Zone
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Just [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) it.

Comment: thank you so much it worked